# Bootstrap dropdown button position and z-index

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to set position and z-index of bootstrap drop down button list ?
Now it appearing behind text and other elements.HTML given below.

```
 <div style="position:relative;">
             <div style="position:absolute;"></div>
             <div class="profile-pic-holder" style="position:absolute;">
                            <div  class="background-fade" >
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    <span>Action Button</span>
                                </a>

                               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li><a href="#" >Action1</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#" >Action2</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Action3</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="#">Action4</a></li>
                                    </ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>

               </div>
```

the dropdown appears behind all other div.Can any one please help?

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9nyUa/)

Comment: create a fiddle please.

Comment: Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/9nyUa/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent div has an `overflow: hidden;`, causing the menu to be hidden by it's parent.

I'd recommend placing the image in an own container, on which you can put an `overflow: hidden;`.

Added to that, I'd recommend placing the CSS in a separate file, and not inline.

I've updated your **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9nyUa/16/)** accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100 or higher till your drop down appears above other elements
}
```